# Formula that execute lookup on first match of a criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

[image: <blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="6E6HW55"><a href="//imgur.com/6E6HW55">View my chart on imgur.com</a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>]

In cell C26, I want to use a formula to print the earliest date at which: Consolidated target > Total # of skus

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `=INDEX(3:3,MATCH(-1,SIGN(C21-24:24),0))`

This is an array formula, so you need to enter it pressing CRTL+SHIFT+ENTER, instead of just enter.

- `SIGN(C21-24:24)` returns the difference of the two rows (I used entire rows, so you don't need to enter the formula if you enter new columns)
- `MATCH(-1,...,0)` - returns the first column's number where previous result is negative
- `=INDEX(3:3,MATCH(...))` results the desired date

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you misunderstood my question: my crieria was "Consolidated target > Total # of skus" and not "Consolidated target > Daily sku target". I modified it and now it works! Cheers! SOLUTION: {=INDEX(3:3,MATCH(-1,SIGN(**C21**-24:24),0))}

Comment: Thanks for the correction @SpidrJeru. Yes, I didn't fully understood your sheet.